# How to compress a File in android?

Tags: android, file

I want to compress a file in android.
I had created a file using **createTempFile**. This is an image file.

Is there any way to compress a file programmatically?

```
private static final String JPEG_FILE_PREFIX = "IMG_FILE";
    private static final String JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX = ".jpg";
    String imgFolderPath = "";
    String imgFolderName = "captureDir";
    File imgDir = null;
    File imgFile = null;
    String mCurrentPhotoPath ="";



if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
                isSDAvailable = true;
                File root = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(); 
                imgDir = new File(root,"/"+imgFolderName);
                imgDir.mkdir();
                try {
                    imgFile = File.createTempFile(JPEG_FILE_PREFIX, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, imgDir);
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(TakePictures.this, "External memory available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                isSDAvailable = false;
                imgFolderPath = "/data/data/"+ this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+ "/"+imgFolderName;
                imgDir = new File(imgFolderPath);
                imgDir.mkdir();
                try {
                    imgFile = File.createTempFile(JPEG_FILE_PREFIX, JPEG_FILE_SUFFIX, imgDir);
                    mCurrentPhotoPath = imgFile.getAbsolutePath();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                //Toast.makeText(TakePictures.this, "External memory not available", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: if you already created a tmp image file, what formar is it?

Comment: It is a JPEG image format.

Comment: so its already compressed, what more do you want?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can look at the [zip package](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/package-summary.html) but if it's only one image and it's a jpg file, zipping it won't have much effect. JPG is already a compressed image format.

If you have more than one image it might make sense to package them into one file, the size won't change however...

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/zip/ZipFile.html

You can use ZipFile

Here is demo http://alvinalexander.com/java/jwarehouse/android/tests/CoreTests/android/core/ZipFileTest.java.shtml

Answer (score -1):

well compressing an image is just about using BitmapFactory and adjusting your compress level inside of

```
Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config)
```

method where config is the parameter you can use to edit the compression level and stuff

Comment: The OP asked specifically about files, your solution is limited to bitmaps